# searching rows with specific string from dataframe returns null in python

Tags: python, pandas

I read pickledata and put into dataframe for further processing. And I found an issue when it comes to choose certain rows that contains special string. 
Below is the first few lines of dataframe.

```
                              parent_pid  \
 0            UXXY-C240-M4L
 2          UXXZ-B200-M5-U
 4          UXXZ-B200-M5-U
 6          UXXZ-B200-M5-U
 8          UXXZ-B200-M5-U
                                                      pid
 0      UXXY-F-H19001,UXX-SD480G...
 2      UXX-SD-32G-S,UXX-ML-X64G...
 4      UXX-SD-32G-S,UXX-SD-32G-...
 6      UXX-SD-32G-S,UXX-MR-X32G...
 8      UXX-SD-32G-S,UXX-MR-X32G...
```

when it comes to search rows that contains "UXXZ-B200-M5-U", I used below codes.

```
 df.query('parent_pid == "UXXZ-B200-M5-U"')
```

And below is the return.

```
 Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [parent_pid, pid]
 Index: []
```

I used many different ways to search rows with this string, it returns the same.
whitespace in the columns doesn't seem to matter.

```
 df[df["parent_pid"].isin(["UXXZ-B200-M5-U"])]
 df.filter(like="UXXZ-B200-M5-U").columns
```

Does anyone know what's the issue here?

Comment: Leading/Trailing spaces. Try: `df[df['parent_pid'].str.strip() == "UXXZ-B200-M5-U"]`

Comment: I already removed whitespace as you mentioned but it returns the same result. and df.filter(like ) or df.contains()  should be able to ignore whitespace and only search the string. unfortunately, no luck to get extract either.

Comment: `print(df.head().to_dict())` and please paste the output in your question.

Comment: Ok... so why do you have all those unprintable characters in your data? Do you not think that could be a reason for your comparisons not working?

Comment: Are you referring to "\x00"added to each characters? I'm not sure how was this added.. As you see the dataset above, it is not there. I pull the data from hive and save into the pickle. maybe is this added from pulling hive data? is there any way to remove them?

Comment: Yes, `\x00` is a null character. Try `print('b\x00b')` and then `'b\x00b' == 'bb'` and you'll see. Now, you'll need to get rid of those. `df = df.replace('\x00', '')` and try your code again.

Comment: got it.. I will try it out. thanks for your guidance.